# Swift sub view hold old values (stacking new values on top of it)

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel

**[solved :)
by adding    self.progressScrollView?.removeFromSuperview()  ]**

I am new to swift.
and having below issue :( please help me.

[image]

every time I come back to this main screen (using back button)
my scroll view's content are showing new values on top of old values

for example.

I have 4 items(a,b,c,d) in an array.
and main page show in random order

```
a
b
c
d
```

after that, i went to another page and came back to this screen.

it shows new values on top of old values

```
a -> b (this value is on top of 'a')
b -> d (this value is on top of 'b')
c -> c (this value is on top of 'c')
d -> a (this value is on top of 'd')
```

**what I did?**

1. I re-initialize my array in viewdidappear()
2. added below in gotopage()
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
3. add removefromsuperview & view.addsubview in self.displayProgressBar()
   (what @sandeep suggested.. but doesn't work)

**my flow:**

1.call displayprogressbar in viewdidload
self.displayProgressBar()

```swift
    class ViewController: UIViewController ,ChartViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
...
    
    var progressScrollView: UIScrollView!
...
         override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
             
                self.getfirebasedata()
```

2.add progress bars and labels dynamically based on the list size.

```swift
     func getfirebasedata(...){ 
      ...
        self.displayProgressBar(...)
     }
    func displayProgressBar(...){     

            self.progressScrollView?.removeFromSuperview() //this is the fix
            self.progressScrollView = UIScrollView()
             
            self.progressScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.progressScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300,
                                                                  width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
                self.progressScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                        height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            let axisXstartPoint = ( self.view.frame.size.width - 200 ) / 2
          
            let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
      ...
            
            let label = UILabel()
          
            label.frame = CGRect(x: axisXstartPoint, y: CGFloat(axisY-15), width: 200, height: 20)
            label.textAlignment = .left
            label.text = book.bookName
    
            label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            label.addGestureRecognizer(tapBookName)
            progressScrollView.addSubview(label)
            progressScrollView.addSubview(progressView)
           
            self.view.addSubview(progressScrollView)
            
        }
```

3. when I go to another page I use this method

```swift
@objc @IBAction func goToAddPage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let label = sender.view as? UIButton
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let addViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "add") as! AddViewController

        addViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addViewController, animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
```

4.this is my storyboard
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure from where you call `displayProgressBar` as its not clear from your question, what you can do is add these statement as either 1st statment in `displayProgressBar` or as a statement before calling `displayProgressBar`

**Approach 1:**

```
self.progressScrollView?.removeFromSuperview() //? because for the first time implicit optional will be nil
self.progressScrollView = UIScrollView()
```

In `ViewDidLoad` you have `self.view.removeFromSuperview()` which I have no idea why? Makes no sense to me why would you try to remove ViewController's view? May be you were trying to remove subviews I assume, if yes, thats not the proper way to remove subviews, you iterate over subViews and call `removeFromSuperview` on each subView, but I dont think you need that, clearly from your code you hold a reference to `progressScrollView` somewhere in your code, just remove it from subview and recreate the `progressScrollView` as

`progressScrollView = UIScrollView()`

And if you are not holding a reference to `progressScrollView` and instead you were creating it as only local variable in `displayProgressBar` method, hold a reference to this view, to do that declare a instance variable `var progressScrollView: UIScrollView!`

**Approach 2:**

And if you dont prefer creating progressScrollView() again and again, you can always iterate over its subviews and remove them from superview one by one

```
        for view in progressScrollView.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Make sure you run `self.view.addSubview(progressScrollView)` only once (like in `ViewDidLoad` or somewhere) if you decide to go with approach 2.

In either case you need to hold a reference to `progressScrollView`

Comment: hi there, thanks for your reply.  approach 1 .. I don't know why my scrollview is gone. ;( trying approach 2....  also I did 'In ViewDidLoad you have self.view.removeFromSuperview() which I have no idea why? ' ==> i just do some experiment to fix this ;(

Comment: you are doing multiple things, just wait either follow approach 1 or approach 2. Lets start with approach one. Where have you added `self.progressScrollView.removeFromSuperview() self.progressScrollView = UIScrollView()` please edit your question and update with code once done, I would rather place it in `displayProgressBar`. Also have you declared a instance variable `var progressScrollView: UIScrollView!` as I mentioned?

Comment: hi, I have updated my code. still the same(scroll bar disappeared ).  I tried var progressScrollView: UIScrollView!==> this one also the same. and if I do var progressScrollView: UIScrollView! , I can't add self.progressScrollView = UIScrollView(). as my scrollview haven't initialised.

Comment: @energy: You have not added any constraint to scroll view nor you have provided any frames to it so is the case with `label` and `progressView` hence none of them are showing up

Comment: hi sandeep, i updated my code.  yes, it was due to the missing constraint. but even I added, the behaviour is the same .    please refer to my updated code. and thank you for your help!!

Comment: hi, i got it. yes it is working now.  i add    self.progressScrollView?.removeFromSuperview()   at right place. but do u know what it is overriding? i mean when i navigate to another page.. isn't my viewcontroller destoryed?

Comment: @energy: nope, "i mean when i navigate to another page.. isn't my viewcontroller destoryed?" Question is very vague, lemme try to explain, might not be able to cover all scenarios, 1. if you push another view controller on your own view controller, your view controller is in navigation stack thats how you come back to this screen when you tap back button so it is definitely not destroyed, 2. If you present view controller over your view controller, you have presented a view controller on your existing view controller, its obviously there in stack it cant be destoryed, your view controller is

Comment: destroyed only when its no longer needed in navigation stack, assume your view controller is the one that is presented/pushed by some other view controller, you close the screen/hit back button, now your view controller is no longer needed in stack, so obviously its dealloc will be called, presenting/pushing a view controller on top of your existing view controller will only hide your view controller but wont be destroyed

Comment: hi sandeep, ok thanks. understand roughly haha. i am still very new to swift. is there a way to destroy a controller before navigate to another view? i though dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil). this is the one that destory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229808/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-energy).